# Invalid Json Response with valid Json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, datatables

I am trying to use the Ajax syntax for datatables and angularjs

I am getting an invalid json response with this =

```
self.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource([{
"id": 860,
"firstName": "Superman",
"lastName": "Yoda"
}])
```

But I am not getting an invalid response with this =

```
self.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/data.json')
.withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

Why is this? The first single item is valid json... verified on http://jsonlint.com/

original example 
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withAjax

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the validity of the json but the type of parameters that the fromSource function accepts.
Try creating a local data.json:

```
[{
   "id": 860,
   "firstName": "Superman",
   "lastName": "Yoda"
}]
```

and then change your code to

```
self.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('path/to/data.json');
```

Comment: The above answer could work.  However what I believe the ideal answer was - I needed to use .fromFnPromise()  and return a promise.  I currently have it calling a angularjs service that uses a $http.get method to generate the promise.  I will look into using the $q to see how to defer the promise later on...

Comment: Yes it would probably be better to use the promise api.
Check out the link to the duplicated question, you have an example of how to use the $q instead of $http, it's fairly easy and straightforward. Good luck!